# How to switch to a vim buffer containing a specific pattern

Tags: vim

I am looking for a way to switch to a buffer containing searched text.

E.g. If I have 100 buffers open, I want to switch to a buffer, that contains 'fooBar = 1'

Comment: Good question. You mighty already know you can do a quickfix search and switch buffers through its window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a plugin for that: [Buffer-grep](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Buffer-grep)

As stated in its README:

```
Use
  Bgrep /expression/
to search all buffers for an expression and put it in a new quickfix list.
```

One could write a function to jump directly to the first one if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a Vim plugin to do this: [buffersaurus](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3620) .

The command `:Bsgrep <pattern>` will use (Vim-dialect) grep to search through all open buffers, identify all matching lines, and present the results in a new window/split. You can "walk through" all the matches using regular Vim movement keys, and open selected matches in the previous window or in a new split/tabpage. Results can be filtered again. You can opt to show contextual lines as well.